# How do I create a scatter plot for all but some column values?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a scatter plot that contains all the values in the `df["terms"]` column except those in the `redundant_terms` list.

The `get_plot` function:

```
def get_plot(library_name):
    df, df_exists = download_library(library_name)
    if not df_exists:
        return -1, -1
    
    enrich_results = get_enrichment_results(genes, df)
    
    # add p value to the dataframe
    df['pvalue'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_pvalue(row, enrich_results), axis=1)

    # get appropriate color and size attributes
    color_mapper = get_colors(df)

    # normalize pvalues for coloring
    norm_pval = colors.Normalize(-1, 1)

    # get top 5 for each cluster
    top_terms = get_top_10(df)

    # add attributes to df
    df['color'] = df['cluster'].apply(lambda x: color_mapper[x])
    df['lw'] = df['term'].apply(lambda x: 2 if x in top_terms else 0.5)
    df['la'] = df['term'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in top_terms else 0)
    df['size'] = df['pvalue'].apply(lambda x: 12 if x < significance_value else 5)
    df['fa'] = df['pvalue'].apply(lambda x: norm_pval(-np.log10(x)))

    if len(enrich_results.keys()) == 0:
        display(HTML(f"<div style='font-size:1.5rem; padding:1rem 0;'>There are no enriched terms for your input gene set in the <b>{library_name}</b> library.</div>"))
        tooltips = [
            ("Gene Set", "@gene_set"),
            ("Cluster", "@label")
        ]
    
    else: 
        tooltips = [
            ("Gene Set", "@gene_set"),
            ("p-value", "@p_value"),
            ("Cluster", "@label")
        ]
        
    hover_emb = HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips)
    tools_emb = [hover_emb, 'pan', 'wheel_zoom', 'reset', 'save']

    plot_emb = figure(
        plot_width=900, 
        plot_height=700, 
        tools=tools_emb
    )

    source = ColumnDataSource(
        data=dict(
            x = df['x'],
            y = df['y'],
            gene_set = df['term'],
            p_value = df['pvalue'],
            sizes = df['size'],
            colors = df['color'],
            fill_alphas = df['fa'],
            label = df['cluster'],
            line_widths = df['lw'],
            line_alphas = df['la'],
            line_colors = ['#000000']*df.shape[0]
        )
    )

    # hide axis labels and grid lines
    plot_emb.xaxis.major_tick_line_color = None
    plot_emb.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None
    plot_emb.yaxis.major_tick_line_color = None
    plot_emb.yaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None
    plot_emb.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '0pt'
    plot_emb.yaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '0pt' 

    plot_emb.output_backend = "svg"    
    
    plot_emb.xaxis.axis_label = "UMAP_1"
    plot_emb.yaxis.axis_label = "UMAP_2"
    
    s = plot_emb.scatter(
            'x', 
            'y', 
            size = 'sizes', 
            source = source, 
            color = 'colors', 
            fill_alpha = 'fill_alphas',
            line_alpha = 'line_alphas',
            line_width = 'line_widths',
            line_color = 'line_colors',
            legend_group = 'label'
        )

    plot_emb.add_layout(plot_emb.legend[0], 'right')
    
    return plot_emb, df
```

code for plotting:

```
gene_list_input = ['CALML6', 'CALML3', 'CALML4', 'ACTB', 'CRKL', 'AKT2', 'RASSF5', 'AKT3', 'KDR', 'AKT1', 'PLCE1', 'PRKCG', 'PRKCI', 'PRKCB', 'PRKCA', 'TIAM1', 'ADCY9', 'PRKD3', 'PARD3', 'PFN4', 'PRKD2']
enrichr_library = 'KEGG_2021_Human'

plot, df = get_plot(enrichr_library)
if plot == -1:
    display(HTML("<div style='font-size:1rem;'>Unable to create scatter plot visualization.</div>"))

else:
    redundant_terms = ["Escherichia coli", "*osis", "virus", "Pathways in cancer",  "Cushing syndrome", "leukemia", "Melanogenesis", "Glioma", "cardiomyocyte", "infection", "disease", "cardiomyopathy", "osteoclast", "Circadian", "addiction", "atherosclerosis", "carcinoma", "diabetes", "Melanoma", "Hepatitis"]

    # Remove redundant terms
    for i in redundant_terms:
        df = df[~df.term.str.contains(i)]
    display(HTML(f"<div style='font-size:1.5rem;'>Scatter plot visualization for {enrichr_library}.</div>"))
    show(plot)
    display(Markdown(caption1))
```

`df`

```
array([[8.634657, 5.6288424, 'Cluster 0', 'ABC transporters',
        'ABCA2 ABCC4 ABCG8 ABCC5 ABCA3 ABCC2 ABCA1 ABCC3 ABCC8 ABCA6 ABCA7 ABCC9 ABCA4 ABCC6 ABCA5 TAP2 TAP1 ABCA8 ABCA9 ABCA10 ABCB10 ABCA12 ABCB11 ABCC10 ABCG1 ABCG4 ABCC1 ABCG5 ABCG2 CFTR ABCB4 ABCD3 ABCB1 ABCD4 ABCB7 ABCB8 ABCB5 ABCB6 ABCB9 ABCA13 ABCC11 DEFB1 ABCC12 ABCD1 ABCD2 ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [8.590188, 6.436214, 'Cluster 0',
        'Mucin type O-glycan biosynthesis',
        'GALNT8 GALNT7 GALNT6 GALNT5 GALNT4 GALNT3 C1GALT1 GALNT2 GALNT1 B3GNT6 GALNTL6 GALNTL5 B3GNT3 ST6GALNAC4 POC1B-GALNT4 C1GALT1C1L B4GALT5 GALNT13 GALNT12 ST6GALNAC1 ST6GALNAC2 GALNT15 ST6GALNAC3 GALNT14 GALNT17 GALNT16 GCNT1 GALNT18 GALNT11 GALNT10 C1GALT1C1 GCNT3 GCNT4 ST3GAL1 ST3GAL2 GALNT9 ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [8.753851, 6.1627917, 'Cluster 0', 'N-Glycan biosynthesis',
        'SRD5A3 DOLPP1 ALG14 MOGS ALG13 ALG12 ALG11 ALG10 DPM1 DPM2 DPM3 ALG10B B4GALT3 DPAGT1 B4GALT1 B4GALT2 RPN1 TUSC3 RPN2 FUT8 MGAT5B MAN1A2 MAN1A1 ALG9 ST6GAL2 ALG8 ST6GAL1 ALG5 ALG6 ALG3 DOLK ALG1 ALG2 MGAT4D DDOST MGAT4A MGAT4B DAD1 MGAT4C MAN1B1 STT3B STT3A GANAB MAN2A2 MGAT5 MAN1C1 MGAT2 MAN2A1 MGAT3 MGAT1 ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [9.098114, 6.7141457, 'Cluster 0',
        'Nicotinate and nicotinamide metabolism',
        'SIRT5 SIRT6 SIRT7 NMNAT3 SIRT1 SIRT2 SIRT3 SIRT4 NT5C1A BST1 NMNAT2 NMNAT1 NT5C1B NT5C1B-RDH14 NNMT QPRT NADSYN1 NT5C2 NUDT12 PNP NT5E NNT NAMPT ENPP1 NMRK2 NT5C NMRK1 NAPRT AOX1 ENPP3 NT5M CD38 ASPDH NADK NADK2 ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [8.627528, 6.6753273, 'Cluster 0', 'Non-homologous end-joining',
        'DCLRE1C FEN1 XRCC5 XRCC6 XRCC4 DNTT LIG4 PRKDC RAD50 POLM POLL MRE11 NHEJ1 ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [8.104685, 6.620231, 'Cluster 0', 'Notch signaling pathway',
        'PSENEN TLE4 TLE3 TLE2 TLE1 DTX3L TLE7 TLE6 KAT2B NCOR2 KAT2A MFNG NUMB RBPJL MAML3 MAML2 MAML1 DTX1 DTX2 DTX3 RFNG DTX4 DLL1 DLL3 DLL4 ATXN1L APH1B APH1A DVL1 DVL2 DVL3 CIR1 HES1 ATXN1 NUMBL NCSTN HES5 CREBBP JAG1 PTCRA JAG2 HEYL SNW1 ADAM17 NOTCH3 NOTCH4 NOTCH1 NOTCH2 HDAC1 CTBP2 HDAC2 CTBP1 PSEN1 PSEN2 RBPJ LFNG HEY2 HEY1 EP300 ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [8.42527, 7.402927, 'Cluster 0', 'Nucleotide excision repair',
        'GTF2H2C_2 RFC4 RFC5 RFC2 LIG1 RFC3 RFC1 RPA2 RPA3 GTF2H1 RAD23B GTF2H2 RPA1 GTF2H3 RAD23A GTF2H4 BIVM-ERCC5 GTF2H5 RBX1 DDB2 CUL4B ERCC1 CUL4A DDB1 CDK7 ERCC4 ERCC5 POLE2 POLE3 ERCC2 RPA4 POLE4 ERCC3 ERCC8 ERCC6 GTF2H2C MNAT1 PCNA CETN2 CCNH XPA XPC POLD4 POLE POLD1 POLD2 POLD3 ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [8.434592, 5.577004, 'Cluster 0', 'Olfactory transduction',
        'OR11G2 OR2L8 OR1J4 OR2L5 OR2L3 OR1J2 OR1J1 OR4P4 OR2L2 OR6T1 OR4K13 OR4K17 OR4K15 OR4K14 OR13J1 ADCY3 OR2K2 OR1I1 OR10AC1 OR6S1 OR5M11 OR5M10 GNG7 OR10D3 OR4N4C OR8B12 OR14K1 OR10C1 OR4N5 OR2J3 OR4N4 OR2J2 OR2J1 OR5P3 OR4N2 OR5P2 OR13H1 OR14J1 OR7A10 OR8U9 OR8U8 OR1G1 OR4M2 OR4M1 OR6Q1 OR8U3 OR8U1 PRKACG OR56B1 PRKACB OR56B4 OR7A17 PRKACA OR52A1 OR1N2 OR1N1 OR5V1 OR6X1 OR52A5 OR10H2 OR10H1 OR10H4 OR10H3 OR10H5 OR1M1 OR4S2 OR2AG1 OR4S1 OR2AG2 OR10G3 OR10G2 OR1L8 OR10G4 OR1L6 OR1L4 OR1L3 OR1L1 OR5T3 OR5T2 OR5T1 OR6V1 OR10G7 OR10G6 OR10G9 OR10G8 OR11H1 OR11H2 OR11H4 OR2M7 OR2M5 OR2M4 OR2M3 OR1K1 OR2M2 SLC8A1 OR4Q3 SLC8A2 OR4Q2 SLC8A3 OR1F12 OR2AE1 OR11H7 OR11H6 OR14A16 OR5AS1 OR2T8 OR2T7 OR2T6 OR13C8 OR51T1 OR2T5 OR2T4 OR2T3 OR2T2 OR13C9 OR2T1 OR2L13 OR4X2 OR4X1 OR9A4 OR9A2 OR13C2 OR13C4 OR13C3 OR13C5 OR5AR1 OR2S2 OR1Q1 OR51S1 OR4A47 OR14C36 OR5B21 OR13A1 CNGB1 OR7E24 OR5W2 OR51Q1 OR6Y1 OR5B12 OR5AP2 OR5B17 OR6C70 OR14I1 OR6C76 OR6C75 OR13G1 OR6C74 OR7A5 OR56A1 OR10A3 OR10A2 OR10A5 OR56A5 OR10A4 OR56A4 OR10A7 OR56A3 OR10A6 OR6C65 OR13F1 OR2W3 OR8B8 OR2W1 CNGA2 OR12D2 CNGA3 OR8B4 OR12D1 CNGA4 OR8B3 OR6C68 OR12D3 OR8B2 PRKG2 PRKG1 OR5AU1 OR51V1 OR2V2 OR2V1 OR8A1 OR11A1 SLC24A4 ARRB2 OR52W1 OR1S2 OR1S1 ARRB1 OR13D1 OR8H3 OR8H2 OR8H1 OR52M1 OR10V1 OR4C13 OR4C12 OR6C6 OR4C11 OR2AT4 CALM2 OR6C4 CALM3 OR4C16 OR6C3 OR5A2 OR8G5 OR5AK2 OR4C15 OR5A1 OR6C2 CALM1 OR6C1 OR8G1 OR9I1 CALML6 CALML3 CALML4 CALML5 OR51J1 OR52L1 OR6B3 OR7D4 OR6B2 OR7D2 OR2A25 OR6B1 OR51I2 OR52K2 OR51I1 OR52K1 OR10T2 OR2A12 OR9G9 OR4D11 OR4D10 OR2Z1 OR6A2 OR7C2 OR9G4 OR2A14 OR7C1 OR9G1 OR52J3 PDE1C PDE1B PDE1A OR10R2 OR10S1 PDE2A OR2Y1 OR8D4 OR8D2 OR8D1 OR4D2 OR4D1 OR5F1 GNG13 OR10Z1 OR52R1 OR4A15 OR4C6 OR4C5 OR3A3 OR4A16 OR4C3 OR3A2 OR14A2 GUCY2D OR3A1 OR8K5 OR8K3 OR8K1 OR4C46 OR4C45 OR5AN1 OR4B1 OR8J3 OR6F1 OR8J1 OR51M1 ANO2 OR10X1 OR4A5 OR5C1 OR7G3 OR7G2 OR8I2 OR7G1 OR9K2 OR2A42 OR52N2 OR51L1 OR52N1 OR52N5 OR52N4 OR10W1 OR5D18 OR5D13 OR5AL1 OR5B3 OR5D16 OR5B2 OR5D14 OR52E1 OR2D3 OR1B1 OR2D2 OR52E5 OR52E4 OR5J2 OR52E2 OR5AC2 OR52E8 OR52E6 OR2C3 OR1A2 OR6K6 OR1A1 OR2C1 OR51B2 OR6K3 OR5I1 OR6K2 OR52D1 OR9Q2 OR9Q1 OR2AK2 OR51B6 OR51B5 OR51B4 OR2B6 OR4F6 OR2B3 OR4F5 OR5H6 OR10K2 OR2B2 OR4F4 OR4F3 OR5H2 OR51A2 OR5H1 OR6J1 OR10K1 GNAL OR2AJ1 GNB1 OR51A4 OR2A7 OR2A5 OR2A4 OR51A7 OR2A2 OR10J1 OR2A1 OR4E2 OR10J4 OR10J3 OR4E1 OR52B2 OR10J5 OR11L1 RGS2 OR52B6 OR4D9 OR52B4 OR4D6 OR4D5 OR51G2 OR51G1 OR52I2 OR1F1 OR2H2 OR10Q1 OR2H1 OR4L1 OR52I1 OR6P1 OR2B11 OR2AP1 OR51F2 OR5M9 OR2G6 OR51F1 OR5M8 OR52H1 OR4K5 OR1E2 OR2G3 OR1E1 OR11H12 OR2G2 OR4K3 OR4K2 OR5M3 NCALD OR4K1 OR5M1 OR10AG1 OR10P1 OR2T35 OR8S1 OR2T33 OR2T34 OR4F29 GRK2 GRK3 OR4F21 OR51E2 OR1D5 OR2T29 OR51E1 OR1D4 OR2T27 OR1D2 OR2F2 OR2F1 OR5L2 OR10AD1 OR6N2 OR5L1 OR6N1 OR4F17 OR4F16 OR4F15 OR51D1 CAMK2D OR1C1 OR5K4 CAMK2A OR5K3 CAMK2B OR5K2 OR5K1 OR2T10 OR6M1 OR2T11 OR2T12 OR5H15 OR5H14 CAMK2G ',
        'Unresolved', 0.15713307684553335, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5,
        0.9018661927141104],
       [8.483766, 7.366049, 'Cluster 0', 'Mismatch repair',
        'PCNA RFC4 RFC5 MLH1 RFC2 LIG1 RFC3 RFC1 RPA2 RPA3 RPA1 MSH2 MLH3 POLD4 EXO1 MSH3 POLD1 POLD2 RPA4 POLD3 MSH6 SSBP1 PMS2 ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [9.422321, 6.61524, 'Cluster 0', 'One carbon pool by folate',
        'MTFMT DHFR2 ALDH1L2 ALDH1L1 SHMT2 AMT SHMT1 ST20-MTHFS MTHFR MTHFS MTR TYMS DHFR FTCD ATIC MTHFD2 MTHFD2L MTHFD1L MTHFD1 GART ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [8.620068, 6.4881454, 'Cluster 0',
        'Other types of O-glycan biosynthesis',
        'GALNT8 GALNT7 GALNT6 ST6GAL2 GALNT5 GALNT4 GALNT3 ST6GAL1 C1GALT1 GALNT2 GALNT1 MFNG EOGT GALNTL6 GALNTL5 OGT POC1B-GALNT4 C1GALT1C1L B4GALT3 GALNT13 POGLUT1 GALNT12 B4GALT1 GALNT15 B4GALT2 GALNT14 XXYLT1 GALNT17 GALNT16 POMT1 POMT2 GALNT18 GXYLT2 GXYLT1 B3GLCT PLOD3 RFNG GALNT11 GALNT10 LFNG C1GALT1C1 POFUT1 POFUT2 COLGALT1 COLGALT2 ST3GAL3 GALNT9 ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [9.2587, 7.3618956, 'Cluster 0', 'PPAR signaling pathway',
        'GK ACSL3 HMGCS2 MMP1 HMGCS1 ACSL1 APOA2 ACSL6 APOA5 ACSL5 ACSL4 SCD ACOX3 ACOX2 APOA1 ACOX1 SLC27A2 SLC27A1 ILK AQP7 UCP1 EHHADH DBI CYP7A1 RXRA PLTP RXRB CPT2 ME1 ME3 RXRG CD36 PCK2 PCK1 ADIPOQ CPT1B CPT1A PPARA PLIN1 PDPK1 NR1H3 SCD5 SORBS1 CYP8B1 CPT1C FABP2 CYP27A1 FABP3 FABP4 FABP5 FABP6 FABP7 APOC3 ANGPTL4 PLIN5 PPARG PLIN4 ACSBG2 PLIN2 ACSBG1 SLC27A4 PPARD SLC27A6 FABP1 SLC27A5 LPL GK2 ACADM UBC ACADL SCP2 ACAA1 OLR1 FADS2 ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [9.647121, 6.9818707, 'Cluster 0',
        'Pantothenate and CoA biosynthesis',
        'PANK3 PANK1 PANK2 DPYS GADL1 PPCS PPCDC UPB1 COASY ALDH3A2 VNN1 VNN2 VNN3 ALDH1B1 ALDH2 DPYD ENPP1 ENPP3 BCAT2 BCAT1 AASDHPPT ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [9.352682, 7.3525085, 'Cluster 0', 'Peroxisome',
        'PEX19 ACOT8 PHYH ACSL3 ECH1 ACSL1 PEX1 PEX10 ACSL6 PEX3 ACSL5 ACSL4 PEX12 PEX2 PEX13 PEX14 PEX16 DAO PEX5L ACOX3 PEX5 ACOX2 PXMP2 PEX7 ACOX1 PEX6 PXMP4 FAR1 FAR2 PEX11G PAOX CRAT SLC27A2 HMGCLL1 PEX11A PEX11B MPV17L2 HSD17B4 EHHADH CROT PEX26 PMVK PIPOX HAO2 HAO1 IDH1 GSTK1 IDH2 EPHX2 DHRS4 SOD1 BAAT SOD2 SLC25A17 CAT AMACR AGPS GNPAT AGXT MVK ABCD3 ABCD4 PECR MPV17L ECI2 NUDT7 DDO NUDT12 HMGCL PRDX5 SCP2 PRDX1 NUDT19 MPV17 MLYCD XDH NOS2 HACL1 ABCD1 ABCD2 ACAA1 DECR2 ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [9.116793, 6.197119, 'Cluster 0', 'Phenylalanine metabolism',
        'GOT1L1 AOC2 DDC AOC3 GOT2 MAOB GOT1 MAOA TAT MIF GLYAT IL4I1 ALDH3A1 ALDH3B2 ALDH3B1 PAH HPD ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [9.209362, 6.2611303, 'Cluster 0',
        'Phenylalanine, tyrosine and tryptophan biosynthesis',
        'IL4I1 GOT1L1 GOT2 GOT1 TAT PAH ', 'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4',
        0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [8.828031, 6.0532002, 'Cluster 0',
        'Phosphatidylinositol signaling system',
        'IPMK OCRL PLCD1 PLCD4 CALM2 CALM3 PI4K2B PLCD3 CALM1 PI4K2A MTMR1 DGKH MTMR2 DGKG INPP1 MTMR3 MTMR4 DGKE DGKD CALML6 DGKB DGKA CALML3 CALML4 INPPL1 CALML5 MTMR6 MTMR7 MTMR8 PIP4K2A PLCE1 PIP4K2B PIP4K2C PRKCG PRKCB PRKCA DGKZ INPP4B INPP4A PIK3R1 SYNJ2 SYNJ1 DGKQ DGKK DGKI CDS2 CDS1 INPP5D INPP5A PPIP5K1 INPP5B PPIP5K2 INPP5E INPP5F PIP5K1A PIP5K1B PLCG1 PIP5K1C PLCG2 ITPK1 ITPKC PIK3CB PIKFYVE PIK3CA ITPKA ITPKB PI4KB PI4KA PIK3C3 IPPK ITPR2 ITPR3 PIK3R3 PIK3R2 MTM1 ITPR1 PLCZ1 IP6K2 IP6K1 IP6K3 SACM1L PLCB4 PLCB2 PLCB3 PLCB1 MTMR14 PTEN PIK3CD PIK3C2G PIK3C2B PIK3C2A PIP4P1 IMPA1 PIP4P2 IMPA2 BPNT2 CDIPT ',
        'Unresolved', 2.483110372887623e-22, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 12,
        11.302501987933008],
       [8.086946, 6.2157965, 'Cluster 0', 'Other glycan degradation',
        'FUCA1 MANBA GBA HEXA FUCA2 HEXB HEXD GBA2 NEU3 NEU4 GLB1 NEU1 NEU2 MAN2C1 MAN2B2 AGA MAN2B1 ENGASE ',
        'Unresolved', 1.0, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [8.411757, 5.477194, 'Cluster 0',
        'Phosphonate and phosphinate metabolism',
        'PCYT1A PCYT1B PCYT2 CHPT1 CEPT1 SELENOI ', 'Unresolved', 1.0,
        '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5, 0.5],
       [8.956247, 5.466023, 'Cluster 0',
        'Maturity onset diabetes of the young',
        'PKLR PDX1 PAX4 BHLHA15 PAX6 HNF1B MAFA GCK NR5A2 HNF1A IAPP RFX6 NEUROG3 FOXA3 FOXA2 ONECUT1 SLC2A2 HNF4G INS HHEX HNF4A NKX2-2 HES1 MNX1 NKX6-1 NEUROD1 ',
        'Unresolved', 0.23883191014621888, '#1f77b4', 0.5, 0, 5,
        0.8109538239585761]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This question might be useful to more people if you present the simplest possible, reproducible example code that illustrates your problem. It would also be simpler to answer.

Comment: Use `isin`: aka: `df = df[~df.term.isin(redundant_terms)]`